# How to use Python script to change IP of printers which connected to my pc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to change list IP address of printers which connect to my pc on Window 10 os.
I'm going to write Python script to do this task.
Example: **192.168.14.234** change to **10.12.9.14**
Could anyone give me the keyword or hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That really depends on the printers. Maybe they offer a way for you to do that, or maybe they don't. Quite possibly, you can only change the IP by typing it in the printer directly. You should search the web for "change IP remotely {your printer model}".

Comment: This is most likely impractical/pointless as you describe it, simply on a networking basis: if your router is on subnet 192.168.14.x then setting the printer IP address to 10.12.9.14 makes it completely uncontactable. The simplest way to have limited control of the IP address is to configure your router to give each printer a fixed (static) IP address, usually outside its DHCP address range but ALWAYS on the same subnet as the router. So you could allocate 192.168.14.254 to a printer.

Comment: @zvone Thank for quick support. I'm going to search with your suggestion.

Comment: @barny the example isn't realable IP. Thank your quick support.